# Temporary users in Django

Tags: django

I would like to implement temporary users in my project. The reason is that people should be able to auth in my application via Facebook Oauth or Facebook Account Kit.

I've got 2 decisions, but each one is not ideal.

**1)** Create User and TemporaryUser models. The first one will have all info about regular user + unique db fields. This TemporaryUser will have only `phone_number` or `facebook_id`. Temporary user will be created on `auth/` endpoint and response will have `auth_token` to be able perform registration later with all needed fields.

**The issue is:** how will I determine that user is temporary and his `auth_token` is legit only for `registration/` endpoint?

**2)** Create basic User model with 2 types: `regular` or `temporary`. This model will have only general fields. Also there will be different models with OneToOne relation with User. Only Users with type `regular` will be able to have that instances with OneToOne relation.

**The issue is:** User model should have `USERNAME_FIELD` , `REQUIRED_FIELDS` to be able to login by admin panel + users with different types should have different managers.

**UPDATED**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, TimeStampedModel, PermissionsMixin):
    is_regular = models.BooleanField(
        default=False
    )
    id = models.CharField(
        max_length=11,
        primary_key=True,
        default=custom_uuid,
        editable=False
    )
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(
        null=True
    )
    facebook_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=True
    )

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Comment: Why FB users should be temporary? BTW, its not a good idea to use 2 auth models. I don't think you can authenticate a user if its not related to a User model (for 2nd solution)

Comment: @ruddra Flow: front-end authorize user by facebook and gives me facebook_token -> back-end do request with this token and facebook_id will be in return -> back-end checks whether user exists in db -> if yes - auth user, else - it should be created temp user with auth token (to be sure that it's the same user and there is no need to verify user one more tome on registration) -> front-end let user to fill in required fields and than register real user

Comment: in that case, you can create a user with dummy data, or override the Django's own User Model make fewer fields required.

Comment: @ruddra I can't change my fields, all of them should stay required. What if user will close app on screen with all needed fields for users? User will stay with that dummy data on the next login and he will skip registration screen. Also this solution will combine auth/registration endpoints that I don't like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From discussion, there are many ways to tackle this issue. But using two different models for authentication purpose is a bad idea. Because [Django Auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django-contrib-auth) was designed assuming one User Model.

This is how I would have approached:

1. Rather than using `facebook_id`, I would have stored `email` from facebook's graph API. While creating the password, I would have used an unique UUID.
2. Put a **temporary flag**(a Model Boolean Field) to track if the user is registered through social media. So when he tries to login to normal path or registration, I would know that he does not have a password, so I would send him to reset his password. After successful reset password, I would have removed that **temporary flag**.
3. Other information which are absolute necessary, I would have used a separate model to store them. For example:

   ```
   class Profile(models.Model):
       ...
       phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
       user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
   ```

   And checked with login that if the User has a profile or not:

   ```
   if not hasattr(user, 'profile'):
        # redirect to more information page
   ```
4. For other permissions for accessing admin site should be restricted creation through normal registration or social registration. For these users, those fields(`is_staff`, `is_superuser` etc should be False by default. For admin user creation, you can use [createsuperuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/#creating-an-admin-user) command. For staff users, you can later assign a normal user to staff by making the `is_staff` flag `True` from adminsite or `Django Shell`.

#### Update(from comments...)

You can use custom Backend for authenticating facebook user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.db.models import Q

class CustomModelbackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, phone_no=None, password=None, facebook_id=None, **kwargs):
        # Override
        UserModel = User
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(Q(phone_no=phone_no) | Q(facebook_id=facebook_id))
            if password and user.check_password(password):   
                return user
            elif facebook_id:
                return user
        except Exception as e:
            # log exception
```

and add it to [AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#authentication-backends) in `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['path.to.custom_backend.CustomBackend']
```

and call authenticate method like this:

```
 authenticate(phone_no=phone_number, password=password)  # for normal auth
 authenticate(facebook_id=facebook_id)  # for social auth
```

But you can't make your `phone_no` unique as there is chance of the phone_no being empty for social login, but you can put it in `USERNAME_FIELD`. So you will see warnings when you run django developer server(**runserver** command)

#### Update (2)

You can try like this:

```
NORMAL_USER = "N"
OAUTH_USER = "O"
AT_USER = "A"
USER_TYPES=(
    (NORMAL_USER, 'Normal User'),
    (OAUTH_USER, 'Oauth User'),
    (AT_USER, 'Account Toolkit User')
)

class User(...):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)  # it might be unnecessary
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices = USER_TYPES, default=NORMAL_USER)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

    class Meta:
        unique_togather = ('account_type', 'identifier',)


# for Oauth Creation

User.objects.create(account_type=OAUTH_USER, identifier=facebook_id)  # or email

# for Toolkit Creation

User.objects.create(account_type=AT_USER, identifier=phone_number)

# For normal User
User.objects.create(identifier=username, username=username)

#backend, and does not need to use ModelBackend, it will work with adminsite
class CustomBackend(...):
    def authenticate(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            identifier= kwargs.get('username')
            password=kwargs.get('password')
            account_type=kwargs.get('account_type', NORMAL_USER)
            user = User.objects.get(identifier=identifier, account_type=account_type)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except Exception:
            # log exception

# authentication
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
user = authenticate(username=identifier, password=password, account_type=OAUTH_USER)
```

Comment: You wouldn't need a temporary flag for the initial password prompt; a user that hasn't set a password will have a `password_hash` of `None`, where a user that just forgot theirs will just have a mismatching hash when they input the wrong one. The `Profile` pattern is a good one, though, and very often a better way to go than a custom user model. I wouldn't use `hasattr` to check for a profile, though. I'm not sure if the ORM will set that to None or just not create it, and I wouldn't depend on that behavior. `Profile.objects.get(user=user)` might be a little heavy, but it's more concrete.

Comment: @kungphu I am not against `CustomUser` Model. Because the requirement here is to store some data which are absolutely necessary, but does not come through social login(from comments in question). Also, hasattr usage is per documentation found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) (in the 2nd example).

Comment: @ruddra In my application users will not be able to perform registration by email, only Facebook Oauth2 or Account Kit. So I can create Basic User model with id, facebook_id and phone_number. User will be able to register by facebook_id or phone_number. I decided to add flag is_regular (to be sure that user finished registration and he can have profile and other info), but the main problem is that I need something for USERNAME_FIELD.

Comment: @ruddra Than you for your help. I can't put `phone_number` into USERNAME_FIELD as facebook user can have only email, but not always phone_number. One of possible solution is to put `username` into USERNAME_FIELD as each regular user will have it, but I don't like idea to put there dummy data for temporary users

Comment: If you are using custom backend, USERNAME_FIELD will have no effect on your authentication, apart from showing an warning

Comment: @ruddra Will it have effect on admin authentication?

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed that. In that case you can use `AUTHENICATION_BACKEND = ['CustomBackend', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']`

Comment: @ruddra Please, check my Updated section on question. I can put to `USERNAME_FIELD` only fields with `unique=True`. That's why `phone_number` in `USERNAME_FIELD` doesn't suit me.

Comment: @Ernst please check my *Update(2)* section